# Scons command/explicit dependency

Tags: scons

I have a code snippet similar to this:

```
# Compile protobuf headers
env.Protoc(...)
# Move headers to 'include' (compiled via protobuf)    
env.Command([include headers...], [headers...], move_func)
# Compile program (depends on 'include' files)
out2 = SConscript('src/SConscript')
Depends(out2, [include headers...])
```

Basically, I have `Protoc()` compiling protobuf files, then the headers are moved to the 'include' directory by `env.Command()` and finally the program is compiled through a `SConscript` file in the 'src'.

Since these are header files that are being moved (that the src compilation depends on), they are not explicitly defined as a dependency by scons (as far as I understand). Thus, the compilation runs, but the header files haven't been moved so it fails. I have tried exposing the dependency via `Depends()` and `Requires()` without success.

I understand that in the usual case, scons should "figure-out" dependencies, but I don't know how it could do that here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be thinking in "make" ways about your build process, which is the wrong approach when using SCons. You can't order single build steps by putting them in different SConscripts, and then including those in a special order. You have to define proper dependencies between your actual sources (C/CPP files for example) and a target like a program or PDF file. Then SCons is able to figure out the correct build order, and will traverse through the folder structure of your project automatically. If required, it will enter subfolders more than once when the dependency graph (DAG) dictates this. Defining this kind of dependencies between inputs and outputs is usually done, using a Builder...and in your case the Install() builder would be a good fit. Please also regard the hints for #2 in the list of "most frequently-asked FAQs" (  https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions).

Further, I can only recommend to read a little more in the UserGuide ( http://www.scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html ) to get a better feeling for how to do things in a more "SConsy" way. If you get stuck, feel free to ask further questions on our mailing list at scons-users@scons.org (see http://www.scons.org/lists.php ).
Finally, if you have a lot of steps that you want to execute in serial, and that don't require any special input/output files, SCons is probably not the right tool for your current task. It's designed as a file-oriented build system with automatic parallelization in mind, a simple (Python?) script might be better at the mere serial stuff...

Comment: And I also recommend to read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html a second time, especially regarding the "XY" problem...

Comment: Thanks! I do come from more of a make background; however, I feel like my use case is within what scons supports. I think my question wasn't very clear (edited above). Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by the "XY" problem...

Comment: Then you should definitely read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html or simply search the web for this expression.

Comment: I see, I thought it was listed in the article. However, that's exactly why I edited the question to basically be the same as what I'm doing (guess I should have started out with that). Thanks for the `Install()` tip.