# SCons, env.Zip and dependancies

Tags: build, dependencies, zip, scons

I am trying to build a program using SCons scripts. At the end, the product folder is zipped.

Some some reason, env.ZipFile command is messing with the rest of the compilation, causing errors such as "foo.c" does not exist at the following location.

If I remove the zip target, everything works fine.

So, basically, I'd like to make sure that the Zip command is executed ONLY after everything is done.

And the question is: how do I make the Zip command dependent of EVERYTHING else ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us how you're trying to achieve things, i.e. post an exact copy of your SConstruct (or an MWE)? You might also want to check out my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815555/scons-command-explicit-dependency for further insight...

Comment: Unfortunately, It is really complex for me to post code because of confidentiality reasons. However I found a solution that I posted below.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution, don't use ZipFile, use Zip.

Zip is provided directly from SCons and will call ZipFile in a appropriate manner.